# Drools 5.5.0 Instantiate two different object types

Tags: java, datatable, drools

I have two POJO classes (Contract and Account). Using a DecisionTable like the one shown in the picture below I want to instantiate an Account object and set different properties based on some Contract conditions.
[image: Drools Decision Table Example]

I don't understand why the Account() constructor is not called, but the Contract() constructor gets fired.
I've tried to debug using printlns (both in Account and Contract constructors) like this:

```
public Account() {
    super();
    System.out.println("Account created @ " + new Date());
}

public Contract() {
    super();
    System.out.println("Contract created @" + new Date());
}
```

The only output is:

```
[6/1/16 12:39:51:501 FET] 000002a2 SystemOut     O Contract created @Wed Jun 01 12:39:51 FET 2016
```

I can't find a solution to instantiate the `*$account`* object (I don't need a condition). I've also tried declaring a variable using VARIABLES Account $account, but this throws *NullPointerException* when trying to call *`setBankAccount($param)`*.

I would really appreciate any help.

Answer (score 0):

Writing a rule where properties of facts are tested will not call constructors of any Java classes matching the fact types named in the patterns. You should create Account and Contract objects in some Java code, insert them and then call fire all rules. Given matching constraints, rules will fire.

Comment: Thank you very much, after reading your comment I realized I was using Stateless session. Changed my code to use Stateful session, inserted the variables and triggered fireAllRules(). Everything went ok.